# MySQL database to android ListView

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am trying to load data from MySQL database to android ListView.
This one is the example I saw : http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

Here's my code :

```
public class AbCdEfGh extends ActionBarActivity {

private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://merosong.byethost24.com/android_php_files_management/connection.php";
private ListView listView;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //showing a ProgressDialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading", true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_main);

    accessWebService();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choose, menu);
    return true;
}

// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;


    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {


        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        ListDrwaer();

    }



}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[]{url});
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> trackList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("mstracks");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
            String outPut = name + "";
            trackList.add(createEmployee("merosongayush", outPut));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }


    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, trackList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{"merosongayush"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

}

private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String link) {
    HashMap<String, String> finalNameLink = new HashMap<String, String>();
    finalNameLink.put(name, link);
    return finalNameLink;
}
```

}

I'm getting nothing in my android activity.

My connection.php output :

http://merosong.byethost24.com/android_php_files_management/connection.php

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may because your `doInBackground` function is doesn't return anything.

Comment: When I use this url : http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php to load 'employee name' from 'emp_info', everything's okay. Then what's the problem in mine ?

Comment: That's not the cause of the issue, as `jsonResult` is a member variable of the Activity.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I saw this. I can't find any error on your codes if it work properly with [link](cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php)